# I'm trying to copy my game saves from the appdata directory to another drive for backup purposes but the files wont copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to copy my save files for my games from my AppData directory to another drive on my system but the files fail to copy. I'm using robocopy to try to achieve this and am not sure what is going wrong.

The Script I'm using is:

```bash
@echo off
set "source=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData"
set "destination=F:\Game_Saves"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /Z /J /EFSRAW /W:1 /R:0 /REG /XJ
exit /b
```

I've had times where I went to play a game after some drive failure or general errors from my ISCSI drives changing letters and losing my save for my games through Epic Games because of the crappy download system they use and i just want to backup my saves to the other drive and then using duplicati to do a more long term backup and cant seem to find out why the files wont copy. If anyone can help me troubleshoot this I'd be very greatful.

I tried changing flags in my script and setting flags I thought might be helpful to my usage but it hasn't worked. I just dont want to lose my saves as some of them have 100s of hours in them. I should also mention that I want my script to complete as fast as possible which is why I don't have any retries set as the only errors I was running into were "Permission Denied" errors for folders I don't need to backup.

Drive F:\ is just a slow SATA hard drive in my PC and not an ISCSI drive and "copy.bat" my batch script is in the root of F:\

Task Scheduler Settings:

- General:

  - Run whether user is logged in or not - yes
  - Run with highest privileges - yes
- Triggers:

  - Run weekly - yes
  - Stop task if it runs for longer than - 4 hours
  - Enabled - yes
- Actions:

  - Start a Program - yes
  - Program/Script - F:\copy.bat

Comment: We need to know all of the scheduled task settings/configuration, and more information about ,`F:`. Please [Edit] your question to submit all of that.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "the files fail to copy"? Does the task never run? Does the task run, but the robocopy fails? Does the robocopy report success without actually copying the file? Do you not even know whether robocopy succeeded? (Use the /LOG option to get a log file.)

Comment: Robocopy copies all folders but leaves them empty of all files

Comment: What does the log file say? Basically, you have to debug the script.

Comment: I also have the "C:\" drive linked to duplicati as its just a docker container running on my system but it can't access it for some reason so i thought this might be a clunky but good workaround for me

Comment: Dirs : 29629 - 0 failed
files: 152854- 152854 failed

Comment: From what I can see it sees the files in AppData and tries to write them to F:\Game_Saves but it doesn't and it doesn't hard fail

Comment: I just tried manually copying the files and that works fine if that helps to say anything

Comment: Just removed the /EFSRAW flag and it seems to be working right. I will provide an answer with the final outcome if this solved my issue

Comment: There is absolutely no way, you should be copying every non empty directory in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData`, first of all you should be at least getting them from `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming` or less likely `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local`. The Game saves will definitely not be in the root of any of those three directories anyhow. Could you be more specific? Also, why are you using "Run with highest privileges"?

Comment: I'm using a script that I found on www.makeuseof.com as a base and I don't know how to write the script in a way that copies only the directories that i need so im just copying the full AppData directory to the other drive and then using duplicati to selectively pull the saves as the saves are in local and roaming and a few of the config states for the launchers are in locallow and i want to back that up. like i said in a previous comment i know its clunky but it solves my problem of not being able to access the C:\ drive directly with duplicati and i plan to learn so more so its not as clunky

Comment: I also was using "Run with highest privileges" to make sure it wasn't running into errors because i didn't have the right authority level but am going to try and turn that off to see what happens as even I think I shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the /EFSRAW flag worked to copy the files though I'm still unsure as to why it was causing interference in the first place unless it just doesn't allow the copy of un-encrypted files in the first place with that flag set.

Updated script for others if they want to use it though it is clunky as it copies all of AppData and that is around 80 GB for my computer so this is not recommended.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData"
set "destination=F:\Game_Saves"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /Z /J /W:1 /R:0 /REG /XJ /LOG+:copylog.txt
exit /b
```